# Is there a way to write a function argument (wchar_t or char16_t) without using L or u character?

Tags: c++

I have a function which has a parameter of `wchar_t*` or `char16_t*`, for example:

```
void showMsg(char16_t *msg){ // or "wchar_t *msg"
    wcout << msg; 
}
```

As we know we must use L or u before the text like the following:

```
showMsg(u"おはようございます"); // for char16_t* must use "u"
showMsg(L"おはようございます"); // for wchar_t* must use "L"
```

Is there a way or a trick to writing the string argument without using `L` or `u` character?

Comment: Does `#define LONG(x) L##x` count?

Comment: Not really; without the prefix the compiler treats it as a normal ANSI string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: With this macro, `showMsg(LONG("foo"))` is equivalent to `showMsg(L"foo")`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What is the meaning of `##` in this `L##x`?

Comment: It's explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).